# Exception classes organization in Java

Tags: java, exception, code-organization, file-organization

I have many exception classes. F.e.: InvalidMethodParameterException, EntityNotFoundException etc. All have some code like xxx.yyy.zzz and a description literal.
The question is: is there any best practices and techniques to organize the classes and its codes/literals. For now, the way I am doing is to put all codes and literals in other classes and even property files ((. It looks to me very frastrating, because to add one exception, i have to make another changes on other files, not one. And to throw the exception, I use a class with static methods, which throws them. These methods and approaches are not created by me, but where I work. So I would like to offer other more efficient approaches. For example, when I offered to use just simply store each exceptions literal and code inside own class, they just ignored saying it's unefficient and bad practice.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I prefer that error codes associated with an exception be kept in the exception class that uses them. However, convincing someone who prefers to keep them all in one place can be hard, since all in one place gives you a good view of all the error codes in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a system architecture which promotes developer efficiency will far outperform one which promotes execution efficiency, as the former can easily encompass the latter. If making a change to a single module requires you to open and modify multiple modules, the design is not promoting developer efficiency. [My very favorite programming book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) recommends that exception types be motivated by exception handlers. Something like the following:

```
Version 1:
void tryToDoSomething(bool arg) {
    try {
        doSomething(arg); //Throws MyException
    } catch (MyException e) {
        if (e.errorMessage == "Try a different argument")
            tryToDoSomething(!arg);
        else if (e.errorMessage == "Try again")
            tryToDoSomething(arg);
    }
}
Version 2:
//Split the exception so that it can be handled differently
void tryToDoSomething(bool arg) {
    try {
        doSomething(arg); //Throws InvalidArgumentException, NotReadyException
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
        tryToDoSomething(!arg);
    } catch (NotReadyException e) {
        tryToDoSomething(arg);
    }
}
```

A modern compiler can optimize throws to make Version 2 significantly faster, besides being self documenting. This is why exceptions were actually created, as user defined types that the compiler could understand to replace the formerly obtuse error codes that had to be passed around and checked manually.

Anyway, if the error codes are designed to reach the user, I would argue that they are not exceptions but errors and should be thrown as such. You could probably design something like an ErrorFactory which would take a string error code and throw the correct derived type, or you could just throw directly. On the other hand, if the error codes **do not** reach the user, why bother using them?

Comment: That's the way to do it (+1). (About the reference: I find it more interesting that it's the book "clean code" than the fact that it's your very favorite programming book ;)

Comment: @DaveBall Ahh yes, that's just some overblown self importance, don't mind that at all :D

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize them all into one class, which would put everything into one outer class:

```
public OurExceptionsClassTM {

    static final String
        ERROR1 = "123.acd.243",
        ERROR2 = "124.axd.543",
        ... ;

    public static class InvalidMethodParameterException extends Exception { ... }
    ...

    public static throwSpecialException(){ ... }
    ...

}
```

That solves the problem of having to change multiple files and more or less keeps things the way your co-workers are used to.

You could also make it a little more modular, by, for example having a different outer extensions class for each project. The point is that everything related to any given exception will still stay together with that exception.